# How to backup up a Sqlalchmey database?

Tags: python-3.x, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, database-backups

I am trying to backup a database through sqlachemy and save it as a file. I tried using the extension, Flask-AlchemyDumps, but it appears to no longer be supported.

I musted be missing something obvious as this is surly an action a lot of developers want to do. Does anyone know how I should be backing up the database?

Thanks in advance

J Kirkman

Comment: I posted some python code to backup from memory to disk file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67162137/317797

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLAlchemy is an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping) which sits between your code and the database. It's useful if you want to interact with specific rows and relationships without having to keep track of lots of ids and joins.

What you're looking for is a way to dump the entire contents of your DB to disk, presumably so you can restore it later/elsewhere. This is a bulk action, which is your first clue that an ORM may not be a suitable tool. (ORMs tend to be fast enough for small to medium operations, but slow and not ideal for actions which affect 10s of 1000s of rows at once.) And indeed, this isn't usually something you'd use an ORM for, it's a feature of your DB, presumably [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/backup-dump.html) or [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html). If you happen to be using Heroku, you can use their [command line tool](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#creating-a-backup) to do this.